# SQL - complicate JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

In a tutorial I saw this SQL query:

```
SELECT a.id as a_id, a.info as a_info, 
       b.id as b_id, b.info as b_info 
FROM stats AS a 
JOIN stats as b
ON a.id != b.id 
LIMIT 25
```

The query is working well, but now I would need to add the **WHERE** condition. I have the table `users`. The table `stats` contains the column `user_id`.
I try to obtain all users from the table `stats` if `users.city=1` (for example), but I still cannot to find a way, how to achieve that...

My problem is, that I currently have no clue, how to put into the query another JOIN (for table `users`).

I would be grateful for every advice, thank you

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish?  That query isn't really all that useful, or so it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you use the table `stats` two times in your query, you would actually need two joins for the `users` table as well. (for stats A and stats B)

```
SELECT a.id as a_id, a.info as a_info, 
       b.id as b_id, b.info as b_info 
FROM stats AS a 
JOIN stats AS b ON a.id != b.id 
JOIN users AS a_users ON a.user_id = a_users.id
JOIN users AS b_users ON b.user_id = b_users.id
WHERE a_users.city = 1 
   OR b_users.city = 1
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Thank you! Just - `WHERE a_users.city = 1 
   OR b_users.city = 1` why is not there `AND`?

Comment: @user984621 if you use `AND` or `OR` depends on which datasets you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what you've got...

This is what you return

```
SELECT a.id as a_id, a.info as a_info, b.id as b_id, b.info as b_info
```

This is where it comes from

```
FROM stats AS a 
JOIN stats as b on a.id != b.id
```

This is how many you want

```
LIMIT 25
```

So if you want to add the users table, add this after the other joins

```
JOIN users ON a.user_id = users.id
```

and to filter it, add this after the joins

```
WHERE users.city=1
```

Giving

```
SELECT a.id as a_id, a.info as a_info, b.id as b_id, b.info as b_info 
FROM stats AS a 
JOIN stats as b on a.id != b.id 
JOIN users ON a.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.city=1
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: thanks for the message. I would have a question - shouldn't be there instead of `JOIN users ON a.user_id = users.id` this: `JOIN users ON a.user_id = users.id AND b.user_id = users.id` - because I would need the both items (`a` and `b`) from the same city

Comment: Possibly. It depends on what you want. You may need to join to two sets of the user table because a and b may have different users?

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, I've reformatted your original SQL statement to make it readable by humans.

```
SELECT a.id   AS a_id
     , a.info AS a_info
     , b.id   AS b_id
     , b.info AS b_info
  FROM stats a
  JOIN stats b
    ON a.id != b.id 
 LIMIT 25
```

Your current query is almost returning a Cartesian product. Every row from stats is getting matched with every row from stats, except for matching itself.  (Assuming that `stats.id` is a primary key or unique key.)

To add a join to the users table, to limit rows returned from `a`, for example:

```
SELECT a.id   AS a_id
     , a.info AS a_info
     , b.id   AS b_id
     , b.info AS b_info
  FROM stats a
  JOIN users au ON au.id = a.user_id AND au.city=1
  JOIN stats b ON a.id != b.id 
 LIMIT 25
```

If you want to limit rows returned for both `a` and `b`, add another join to the `users` table:

```
SELECT a.id   AS a_id
     , a.info AS a_info
     , b.id   AS b_id
     , b.info AS b_info
  FROM stats a
  JOIN users au ON au.id = a.user_id AND au.city=1
  JOIN stats b ON a.id != b.id 
  JOIN users bu ON bu.id = b.user_id AND bu.city=1
 LIMIT 25
```

This is not the only way to accomplish this. For example, you could use an `a.user_id IN (subquery)` or an `EXISTS (subquery)` predicate.

(SQL is much easier to work with if you have it formatted in a way that is readable.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that:

```
SELECT a.id as a_id, a.info as a_info, 
       b.id as b_id, b.info as b_info 
FROM stats AS a 
JOIN stats as b
     ON a.id != b.id 
where a.user_id in (select user_id from users where users.city = 1)
LIMIT 25
```

You can also express this as a join (which in MySQL is more efficient):

```
SELECT a.id as a_id, a.info as a_info, 
       b.id as b_id, b.info as b_info 
FROM stats AS a 
JOIN stats AS b
     ON a.id != b.id 
JOIN users AS u
     ON a.user_id = u.user_id 
     AND u.city_id = 1
LIMIT 25
```